# Cant connect to google services

Tags: java, android

Im using the code that the android dev. site explains how to connect to the google api client. If it fails to connect it opens a dialog that gives you options to solve the issue.

Im running the app on my emulator and when the dialog pops up and gives me the option of "get google play services" and i click it i get the following error:

```
Can't redirect to app settings for Google Play services
```

Can anyone please help me? Perhaps the issue is that im using an emulator- im not sure bc i havent tested it on a real phone. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because you are running on an emulator not based on the Google APIs. There are different types of emulators, namely the default ones and the ones based on Google APIs. For applications where you need to access the Google Play Services, you need to create emulators based on the latter ones.

Something from the following link: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

To test your app when using the Google Play services SDK, you must use either:
•A compatible Android device that runs Android 2.3 or higher and includes Google Play Store.
•The Android emulator with an AVD that runs the Google APIs platform based on Android 4.2.2 or higher.